# Twitter API 1.1 - Retrieving tweets of other users

Tags: api, rest, twitter

I am working on a project, that compiles the tweets of 4 or 5 different twitter accounts related to a particular subject - and I do not control them.

This was possible with the 1.0 API. A simple ajax call to the API would return the JSON, and off you went.

With the implementation of OAuth for Version 1.1, it seems as though it is no longer possible to retrieve the tweets from accounts you do not own.

My question, is there a work around using the current API to retrieve tweets from another user? Perhaps using the `GET search/tweets` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call you need is [`statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

As the documentation says

> Returns a collection of the most recent Tweets posted by the user indicated by the screen_name or user_id parameters.

So, if you want all of my tweets, you would call

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=edent`

You will need to be authenticated with the Twitter API. I suggest that you use a library for your preferred language.